# How to delete instagram like using getjson post method?

Tags: ajax, instagram, getjson, instagram-api

I am trying to delete instagram like . I have valid access token and have the media id of instagram image. I want to use whateverorigin.org so that i dont get cross domain error. when i run the code beleow i dont get any error and even when i press f12 i dont see any error in console!could any one tell me how to fix this getjson?

note:I am looking for non php solution !

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function delete() {



    var url="https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxx/likes?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    $.ajaxSetup({
        method: "post"
        scriptCharset: "utf-8", //maybe "ISO-8859-1"
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

    });

    $.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + 

        encodeURIComponent(url) + '&callback=?',
        function(data) {

    });
    }
    </script>

    <button onclick="delete()">delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Instagram API Documentation](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/likes/) you need to use the "delete" method. In your code you're using a "post" method, which is creating a like.

So, just change method: "post" to method: "delete"